# How to check if it has a class running?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout, tkinter-menu

I made this basic code just to send here to see if I could find a solution.

I wanted the code to do the following: when I pressed the button press it calls the other class with the other button and if I press the button again it will check if the class is still showing so as not to add another X button. of my code for you to see the result and follows a code base for readers to understand.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRJS8.jpg

```
from tkinter import *
class Window:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.frame = Frame(root)
        self.frame.pack(side = LEFT)
        self.frame1 = Frame(root)
        self.frame1.pack()
        self.But = Button(self.frame,text = 'Press', command = self.ButOk)
        self.But.pack(side = LEFT,anchor = E)

    def ButOk(self):
        self.Aux = False
        self.Aux = not self.Aux
        if self.Aux:
            Window1(root)

class Window1:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.fram = Frame(root)
        self.fram.pack(side = LEFT)
        self.fram1 = Frame(root)
        self.fram1.pack()

        self.But = Button(self.fram, text = 'X',command = self.close)
        self.But.pack(side =RIGHT,anchor = W)
    def close(self):
        self.Aux1 = False
        self.Aux1 = not self.Aux1
        if self.Aux1:
            self.fram.pack_forget()
root=Tk()
Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I expect a result in which when the user presses the button, it does not generate this "windows".

Comment: Rethink your approach, read [Switch between two frames in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7557028/7414759)

Comment: @stovfl: I think that's bad advice. Why would switching to more complicated code solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe. As long as @Giovanni don't commented about my advice we will never know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to ensure that multiple windows are not created from the multiple clicks of the button on your root level window.

Please try to use [TopLevel](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) widget when creating multiple windows.
Additionally, you can check if a Toplevel widget exists using the following code:

```
if tkinter.Toplevel.winfo_exists(toplevel_name)==1:
    self.Aux = False
```

Comment: Eeee, now I understand, it worked well here, thank you very much.